# Change of variables for equation with delta x

Tags: stochastic-processes, recurrence-relations

I have the following equation

$$\Delta X = (\lambda - 1)X + p + \sqrt X z(0, \lambda )$$

and I want to apply the change of variables $x = \sqrt X$ to get an expression for $\Delta x$.

Simply replacing the $X$'s gets me an expression for $\Delta x^2$, and I'm unsure of how to proceed from there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have
$$
X_{n+1} - X_n = (\lambda-1)X_n + p + z(0,\lambda) \sqrt{X_n}
$$
and letting $x_k = \sqrt{X_k}$ you have
$$
x_{n+1}^2 - x_n^2= (\lambda-1)x_n^2 + p + z(0,\lambda) x_n
$$
You cannot get $x_{n+1}-x_n$ from here directly since the LHS is
$$
x_{n+1}^2 - x_n^2= \left(x_{n+1} - x_n\right) \left(x_{n+1} + x_n\right) 
$$
but you can move $x_n^2$ to the RHS getting perhaps a simplified form
$$
x_{n+1}^2 = \lambda x_n^2 + p + z(0,\lambda) x_n
$$
which will solving for $x_n$ directly. This implies
$$
x_{n+1} = \sqrt{\lambda x_n^2 + p + z(0,\lambda) x_n}
$$
so
$$
\Delta(x_n)
 = x_{n+1} - x_n
 = \sqrt{\lambda x_n^2 + p + z_0(0,\lambda) x_n}
 - \sqrt{\lambda x_{n-1}^2 + p + z_1(0,\lambda) x_{n-1}}
$$
where $z_0(0,\lambda)$ and $z_1(0,\lambda)$ are likely independent and clearly identically distributed random variables resembling white noise.

Comment: Thanks, not sure why I didn't do that in the first place.